# 123-reg.co.uk website and apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi this is my first time asking a question on here so go a little easy on me if my question is not clear or my code is not right lol. I currently uploaded my new php mvc website to 123-reg.co.uk and im using apache mod_rewrite with a router class. It works perfectly when im on my localhost but when its live, the mod_rewrite is ignored and the controller is not recognised e.g if i type http://www.examplewebsite.co.uk the home controller loads like it should but if i try to load a different controller e.g http://www.examplewebsite.co.uk/images it takes me too a server error 404 page. I have been trying to fix this for several days now with no success, i have done some research and 123-reg.co.uk does support mod_rewrite, i feel like im loosing it haha, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

This is the router class:

```
class Router {

public function __construct()
{
    if(empty($_GET['url']))
    {
        Help::loadApplication('controllers','home');
        return new Home();
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        $url = rtrim($url,'/');
        $url = filter_var($url,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL,true);
        $url = explode('/',$url);

        Help::loadApplication('controllers',$url[0]);
        if(class_exists($url[0]))
        {
            $controller = new $url[0];

            if(isset($url[1]))
            {
                $methodName = $url[1];

                if(method_exists($controller, $methodName))
                {
                    $methodParams = (isset($url[2]) ? $url[2] : false);
                    $controller->{$methodName}($methodParams);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Help::loadApplication('controllers','home');
            return new Home();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /http://www.examplewebsite.co.uk

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

UPDATE !!

Anyone else that has this same issue,  the reason it wasn't working is because 123-reg.co.uk don't support mod_rewrite on their Windows package but do on there Linux package, it would have been good for them to state that when I signed up for the Windows package but making the switch over to the Linux package now. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: remove the `RewriteBase` line, does it work then ?

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't work, its driving me crazy, this has been the hardest part of the whole process lol

Answer (score 0):

This is worth trying;  Add this as your first line above `RewriteEngine On`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

source: http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2222

and I'm not so sure about your RewriteBase, maybe it should be

```
RewriteBase /
```

instead of having the full url?

Comment: I have also tried that, i have just tried it again and still no success

Comment: have you tried asking their tech support?  I saw on another question one of their reps told the OP to contact them for help.

Comment: maybe `RewriteBase http://www.examplewebsite.co.uk/` would work instead of the leading slash?

Comment: Yh i have contacted their support team but i dont know how long they will take to reply so just thought i would ask on here in the meantime. Joe T, i will try that now

Comment: Joe T, i have just tried that and that didn't work either. Its proper baffling me lol, this is the most frustrated i have been in the whole teaching myself web development process haha